# Cannot read property of undefined in spfx

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, react-webpart

Hear is a SPFx react webpart ".tsx" file code image

[image]

Have you any solution ?

Comment: modify it to  `{this.showDialog.bind(this)}` and check ?

Comment: @GautamSheth This is not recommended due to performance reasons and tslint in SPFX solution won't even allow it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use arrow function in `this.state.items.map` `this` in anonymous function has different context and you would have to bind also the anonymous function itself like:

```
this.state.items.map(function (item, key) {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.showDialog}>click</button>
        </div >
    );
}.bind(this));
```

Correct use:

```
this.state.items.map((item, key) => 
    <div>
        <button onClick={this.showDialog}>click</button>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: @Chandresh if the solution is helpful, please accept the answer. Thanks